# Which browsers incorporate enhanced privacy settings?

Tags: browser, privacy

I am looking for a minimal browser with enhanced privacy support. Security should be built-in and not provided by extra add-ons.

Specifically, the things I am looking for are as follows:

1. When connecting to a site, I would like that site to only be able to access my IP address, and no other information.
2. The browser should load only resources from the site specified in the address bar, and not load any other third party addresses.
3. All cookies should be disabled by default. The user should have the ability to white-list certain websites, but their cookies must be sand-boxed and no other site should be able to access them.
4. If JavaScript is enabled, it should have no access to local storage, and it should only be able to launch connections with the site in the address bar alone.

Does such a browser exist? If not, which of the existing browsers comes closest in functionality?

Comment: Many websites would cease to function properly if they cannot load remote resources. See [Content Delivery Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)

Answer (score 1):

Although completely overkill, the best privacy you can get is probably with something like the [TOR browser bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en). You can test the resulting privacy using [Panopticlick](http://panopticlick.eff.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Iron? It is built off of Chrome, but has many of its sharing features disabled. The best part is it retains the same feel and functionality as Chrome.
http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron_chrome_vs_iron.php

This should come close to what you want.