# Browser anonymity

Tags: browser, browser-addons, privacy

As i have understood it when i read the information on the tor homepage and they recomended me not to use extensions/add-ons because browser and extensions/add-ons are shown to whoever i choose to connect to. This, they stated, could be used to recognize me as very few had the same setup of extensions/add-ons.

So my question here is this: Is there a way to hide my extensions/add-ons and browser i am using from those i connect to with my browser?

Comment: the browser exposes a list of plugins/extensions so that sites can offer content specific to the available addons and to install missing plugins if needed.

Comment: Frank Thomas@ Can you make it so that the browser will never do this? Even at the expense of the plugins/extensions ability to work.

Comment: Have you seen [Surfing the web anonymously](http://superuser.com/questions/1820/surfing-the-web-anonymously), [How to hide Browser Plugin Details in firefox for more privacy?](http://superuser.com/questions/436598/how-to-hide-browser-plugin-details-in-firefox-for-more-privacy), [Which browsers incorporate enhanced privacy settings?](http://superuser.com/questions/367324/which-browsers-incorporate-enhanced-privacy-settings), [Browser for paranoid people?](http://superuser.com/questions/102400/browser-for-paranoid-people) or any of the *numerous* related/linked questions already?

Comment: Karan@ I have not read those and i realize that i should have.

Answer (score 0):

It's not only this. It's, too, about extensions being able to contact the server directly, bypassing your Tor proxy thus revealing your real IP address.

Your browser may, indeed, send headers as some other browser, but extensions can change the page behavior and even when they don't bypass your Tor anonymization, they can reveal they do exist. If they didn't, some of them wouldn't even work.

Comment: Okey so extensions can bypass tor. Can extensions bypass VPN protocols such as OpenVPN?

Comment: "extensions being able to contact the server directly" - mitigated by running the torified application (browser or whatever) inside a sandbox that doesn't allow traffic to go anywhere except the local tor.